# Adding additional column "TYPE" in SQL in the resultant table

Tags: sql, oracle

Display id and name for salesmen along with id and category of products in a single table. Indicate the source of the row in result by adding an additional column TYPE with possible values as 'S' (Salesman) and 'P' (Product). Display all rows.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Homework. And what have _you_ tried?

Comment: And post sample data and expected result as text, not as images of text

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The output is in the form of table that's why I posted it in the image form which is more human understandable

Comment: @jarlh I have posted the answer. Check out

Comment: Text can be copied and easily made into test-data for anyone trying to help you while images are completely worthless for this. And the claim that images are more human understandable is just nonsense all you have to do is properly format your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT('S','') "TYPE", SID "ID", SNAME "DETAILS" FROM Salesman UNION ALL SELECT CONCAT('P', '') "TYPE", PRODID "ID", CATEGORY "DETAILS" FROM Product
```

I got the answer, I have tried this above query, it is giving me the answer.

Is there any other way to get the same output?

Comment: It's corect, but you don't need `concat`. Just write `select 'S' as type ... union all select 'P' ...`. There will be duplicated categories, but this is as in requirements.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah, but when I'm trying to do so, it is saying "you can accept your own answer in 20 hours", maybe they have set some time limit for accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

**We can use desired entries in the non-existing columns by enclosing it with quotes followed by as type(i.e 'S' as type)**

select 'S' as type,sid id,sname details from salesman union all select 'P' as type,prodid id,category from Product

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, name, 'S' as TYPE FROM salesmen
UNION ALL
SELECT id, category, 'P' as TYPE FROM products;

Comment: It would be better if you add some explanation along with the code or example output that is expected